# What is more efficient, reading word by word from file or reading a line at a time and splitting the string using C ?

Tags: c, file, processing-efficiency

I want to develop an application in C where I need to check word by word from a file on disk. I've been told that reading a line from file and then splitting it into words is more efficient as less file accesses are required. Is it true?

Comment: Why not try it both ways, and see which way actually is faster?

Comment: I think important consideration is, do line breaks carry special meaning, or are they just like any whitespace? If they are like any whitespace, then in the main loop at least, you should read words, ignoring lines. If you make `readWord` function or something, then in that you can still read and buffer lines, maybe, but if lines have no special meaning in the main loop, don't handle lines in the main loop.

Answer (score 8):

If you know you're going to need the entire file, you may as well be reading it in as large chunks as you can (at the extreme end, you'll memory map the entire file into memory in one go). You are right that this is because less file accesses are needed.

But if your program is not slow, then write it in the way that makes it the fastest and most bug free for you to develop. Early optimization is a grievous sin.

Comment: The alpha version of application has been created with line by line reads.

Comment: If the alpha version works, don't bother to alter it.  If the alpha version has problems, think about using `scanf()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Not really true, assuming you're going to be using `scanf()` and your definition of 'word' matches what `scanf()` treats as a word.

The standard I/O library will buffer the actual disk reads, and reading a line or a word will have essentially the same I/O cost in terms of disk accesses.  If you were to read big chunks of a file using `fread()`, you might get some benefit — at a cost in complexity.

But for reading words, it's likely that `scanf()` and a protective string format specifier such as `%99s` if your array is `char word[100];` would work fine and is probably simpler to code.

If your definition of word is more complex than the definition supported by `scanf()`, then reading lines and splitting is probably easier.

Answer (score 2):

As far as splitting is concerned there is no difference with respect to performance. You are splitting using whitespace in one case and newline in another.

However it would impact in case of word in a way that you would need to allocate buffers M times, while in case of lines it will be N times, where  M>N. So if you are adopting word split approach, try to calculate total memory need first, allocate that much chunk (so you don't end up with fragmented M chunks), and later get M buffers from that chunk. Note that same approach can be applied in lines split but the difference will be less visible.

Comment: +1: Good point about the impact of what else you do with the words than just read them!

Comment: @hyde, do not understand your comment. Do you mean to say that consecutive mallocs would automatically lead to memory being allocated from consecutive chunks, where those buffers eventually get filled by scanf and likes? That's pretty outwittingly smart for file io afaik.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, you should read them in to a buffer, and then split into whatever you define as 'words'.
The only case where this would not be true is if you can get `fscanf()` to correctly grab out what you consider to be words (doubtful).

Answer (score 0):

The major performance bottlenecks will likely be:

- Any call to a stdio file I/O function. The less calls, the less overhead.
- Dynamic memory allocation. Should be done as scarcely as possible. Ultimately, a lot of calls to malloc will cause heap segmentation.

So what it boils down to is a classic programming consideration: you can get either quick execution time or you can get low memory usage. You can't get both, but you can find some suitable middle-ground that is most effective both in terms of execution time and memory consumption.

To one extreme, the fastest possible execution can be obtained by reading the whole file as one big chunk and upload it to dynamic memory. Or to the other extreme, you can read it byte by byte and evaluate it as you read, which might make the program slower but will not use dynamic memory at all.

You will need a fundamental knowledge of various CPU-specific and OS-specific features to optimize the code most effectively. Issues like alignment, cache memory layout, the effectiveness of the underlying API function calls etc etc will all matter.

Why not try a few different ways and benchmark them?

Comment: Stdio file IO functions are not particularily slow. They're buffered. `getc()` is even allowed to be a macro! Using the system calls like `open()`, `read()` etc, these get passed to kernel and they are slow, which is why using stdio `FILE*` functions should be generally preferred, unless you can justify writing and testing and maintaining your own buffering code.

Comment: @Hyde It depends on what you compare with. A Windows programmer might not find them slow, a real time systems programmer will find them terribly inefficient. But of course it all boils down to whatever OS API lies underneath them. You make assumptions about which OS that the op is using, but they posted no such details so we can't tell. For all we know, his system might not even have a OS, although it seems likely.

Comment: If real-time system programmer finds them inefficient, then I'd say it's fault of the C library he's using... As good library code will not be any worse than what he might write himself.

Comment: @Hyde The reason stdio.h is inefficient is because the functions come with a big chunk of overhead tasks they have to support to conform with the standard.

Comment: @hyde Lets for example say we are only interested in printing one single integer and use printf. First our parameter(s) are chewed through the obscure "default argument promotions", possibly making them wider than necessary. Then printf will have to implement the obscure va_list to sort out the variable parameter list. It will then have to implement support for float numbers, strings, characters, large integer types, pointers etc. Then detailed formatting about all those types. Plus support for octal and hex.

Comment: @hyde So if only the actual hardware interface to the screen is pre-made, any beginner programmer can write an immensely faster function than those in stdio.h. Not because stdio.h was clumsily implemented, but because it carries so much overhead from the standard.

Comment: I partly agree, there are certainly cases where this applies, but I doubt reading words from a file is ever among these. Also, `printf` alone is not the best example IMHO, `puts` vs. custom string writer would be better, or direct `printf` vs. `snprintf` + custom writer.

Comment: @hyde If fscanf is used, it certainly applies. If fread is used, perhaps less so.

Comment: Yes, `scanf` of course has the format string overhead, but your answer talks about "any stdio file I/O function" (which prompted my first comment). I doubt `fgets` has significant overhead compared to any custom line read implementation, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually answer to your exact question (words vs lines), but if you need all words in memory at the same time anyway, then the most efficient approach is this:

1. determine file size
2. allocate buffer for entire file *plus one byte*
3. read entire file to the buffer, and put `'\0'` to the extra byte.
4. make a pass over it and count how many words it has
5. allocate `char*` (pointers to words) or `int` (indexes to buffer) index array, with size matching word count
6. make 2nd pass over buffer, and store addresses or indexes to the first letters of words to the index array, and overwrite other bytes in buffer with `'\0'` (end of string marker).

If you have plenty of memory, then it's probably slightly faster to just assume the worst case for number of words: `(filesize+1) / 2` (one letter words with one space in between, with odd number of bytes in file). Also taking the Java ArrayList or Qt QVector approach with the index array, and using `realloc()` to double it's size when word count exceeds current capacity, will be quite efficient (due to doubling=exponential growth, reallocation will not happen many times).